# Factory Pattern Example in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was trying one example in factory pattern. This is giving me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Could someone explain ?

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at com.factory.SalutationFactory.main(SalutationFactory.java:10)
```

Here are my classes.

```
package com.factory;

public class SalutationFactory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try
        {
        SalutationFactory factory = new SalutationFactory();        
        factory.getPerson(args[0], args[1]);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Person getPerson(String name, String gender){

        if(gender.equals("M"))
            return new Male(name);
        else if(gender.equals("F"))
            return new Female(name);
        else 
            return null;
    }
}

package com.factory;

public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String gender;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getGender(){
        return gender;
    }

}

package com.factory;

public class Female extends Person {

    public Female(String fullname){
        System.out.println("Hello Ms " + fullname);
    }
}

package com.factory;

public class Male extends Person {

    public Male(String fullname){
        System.out.println("Hello Mr " + fullname);
    }

}
```

Thanks
Dev

Comment: Please post your exception stack trace!

Comment: Are you passing the command-line args?

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at com.factory.SalutationFactory.main(SalutationFactory.java:10)

Comment: you should validate the length of the `args` array to be at least 2

Comment: The program has also another drawback. You don't need to store the `gender` if you already have a subclass for each gender. This is the same information stored multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is the only line using arrays:

```
 factory.getPerson(args[0], args[1]);
```

I suspect you're not providing 2 command-line args. You'll need something like:

```
$ java com.factory.SalutationFactory Smith M
```

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at com.factory.SalutationFactory.main(SalutationFactory.java:10)    This is the stack trace. Btw, I am using eclipse. So when I run, the console window is not showing displaying. So where would I paas my cmd line arguments ?

Comment: Check Run Configurations in Eclipse. There should be Arguments tab. Provide space separated values. BTW This is again different question.

Comment: Went to Run Configurations -> Arguments tab. Two things are present here. Program arguments and VM arguments. How would I set it to a space separated values ?

Comment: Put "Smith M" under Program Arguments.

Comment: Thank you Brian, Hardik, Jesper and Chandra.

Answer (score 2):

```
factory.getPerson(args[0], args[1]);
```

Here you are using command line argument, so while running this applicatio you have to pass the command line argument

run using

```
java SolutionFactory Santosh M
```

Here **Santosh** will be assigned to **args[0]** and **M** will be assigned to **args[1]**

If without passing any command line argument, you run this program, then **length of args** will be **zero** and inside **main()** you are calling **args[0]** which causes **ArrayIndexOutOfBounds** exception

Comment: Yes Chandra, thas correct. But I am using eclipse. As Hardik said, need to configure eclipse a bit i guess.

Comment: Yes of course. You need configure Run environment of your eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I have try the same example and after  trying here is the solution.Create this code.

```
String []pin =new String[4];
    pin[0]="M";
    pin[1]="F";
    Factory factory = new Factory();
    factory.getPerson(pin[0],pin[1]);
```

this will work

and  your out put should be "female".

Answer (score 0):

You must check for null or objects before just using them. Just add the line

```
if (args.length >= 2)
    factory.getPerson(args[0], args[1]);
/* else 
    Add reminder to provide at least 2 arguments. */
```